# Django, how to send arguments to redirected view

Tags: python, django, django-views

My view function what should receive an argument:

```
def result(request, exercise_field = {"tro": "lolo"}):
    return render(request, "lolapp/result.html", exercise_field)
```

"Exercise_field" is the variable that takes an argument.

Url for that function:

```
url(r'^result/', view = views.result, kwargs = {'lolo': 'roflo'}, name = 'result')
```

As you can see, i tried to pass my argument via "kwargs" keyword. So far - haven't worked out.

Shortcut that calls this View:

```
    return redirect('result', kwargs={'lol': 'rofl'})
```

And finally the error message:

```
Reverse for 'result' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'kwargs': {'lol': 'rofl'}}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['result/']
```

I need to send one argument to "results" view.

And this is typical "NoReverseMatch" error, but no solutions in internet worked for me.

What do i do wrong?

Comment: I believe problem in url.
I need to figure out how to send the argument from one view to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is simple: i should've to use sessions.

Info about sessions: http://machinesaredigging.com/2013/10/29/how-does-a-web-session-work/

How to use sessions in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/

Simply store it within *request.session["my_data_key"]*, and i good to go.

*request.session* is simple python dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

may be just typo:

```
kwargs={'lol': 'rofl'}
```

you should try:

```
kwargs={'lolo': 'rofl'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return redirect('result', kwargs={'lol': 'rofl'})
```

should be for kwargs:

```
mydict = {'lol': 'rofl'}
return redirect('result',passdict=mydict)
```

or simply you can do with args:

```
mydict = {'lol': 'rofl'}
return redirect('result',mydict)
```

Comment: Your suggestion with args helped to clean this problem a little bit, but i still have this problem going.
I believe that problem within the url. I just don't know how to send the argument from one view to another.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL does not accept any arguments at all: the view kwargs are hard-coded. It is therefore impossible for any request - whether a redirect or just a normal request - to pass any kwargs other than the hard coded ones.

You have various options:

- change the URL pattern so it does accept arguments;
- add an extra pattern with the other kwargs hard coded;
- pass the data in the session rather than the kwargs.

Comment: Can you give me an example of first option?

Comment: And currently i try to send my data via session, as you suggested.